# Android Bluetooth connection lost

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

My application is detecting a paired Bluetooth device.
If it's found, my application starts.
And when the connection is lost, my application stops.
But the connection is lost every 10,15 seconds.

How can I solve this?

Comment: My receiver call this after 10,15 seconds  BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED

Comment: Show your code, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` is sent whenever the connection was closed on a HARDWARE level. WHEN that happens is specific to the device itself. If you manually disconnect/plug out the other device, it somehow does not send a closed connection signal to the droid, instead after up to 20 seconds some watchdog runs and the connection is closed and the intent is sent.

As this is specific to the device hardware, go for checking from another device.

Comment: can you please guide me how can i make new request on ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED called. Is it possible keep requesting until the paired device is in range.